# A Non-Compact Topology on $\mathbb{N}$, the Natural Numbers

Tags: general-topology

I am given the following set $\mathcal{T}$ which is a topology on the natural numbers:

$$\mathcal{T}:=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\},\ldots,\mathbb{N}\}$$

I want to show that $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{T})$ is non-compact. To show that a topological space is not compact, I know that I have the following tools to do so:

1. I can show that there does not exist a finite subcover of an open cover of $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{T})$.
2. I can show that there is a collection of closed sets $\mathcal{C}$ in the topological space that does not have the finite intersection property (i.e., the intersection of all the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ is empty).

I am not sure if #2 would be helpful here, and I am not sure how to apply #1 given the topology that I have. How would I go about crafting an open cover (and then showing that such an open cover has no finite subcover)?

Comment: A cover worth looking at in more detail is given by $\mathcal{T} \setminus \{ \mathbb{N} \}$...

Comment: Think about the cover of $\mathbb{N}$ of all the elements of the topology except $\mathbb{N}$ itself.

Comment: If $\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{O}$ then $\mathcal{O}$ has the finite subcover $\{\mathbb{N}\}$. Can you describe an open cover that does not include $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have excellent hints in the comments for how to use $1.$ If you want to use $2.$, you can consider the following decreasing sequence of closed sets:
$$(\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\ldots,n\})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$$
What is $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\ldots,n\})$?